# Passing a boolean parameter to a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, boolean

I asked this question earlier and I thought I found what the problem was, but I didn't. I'm having a problem passing a boolean parameter to a stored procedure. Here's my c# code:

```
public bool upload = false;

protected void showDate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (Radio1.Checked)
        {
            upload = true;
            Radio2.Checked = false;
            date_div.Visible = true;
            date_div2.Visible = false;
        }
}

protected void getMonthList()
{
    selectedYear = year.SelectedValue.ToString();

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString);

    SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    connection.Open();

    cmd.CommandText = "getMonth";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", SqlDbType.Int, 0).Value = Convert.ToInt32(selectedYear);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@upload", upload);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    da.Fill(dt);

    month.DataSource = dt;
    month.DataTextField = "month";
    month.DataValueField = "monthValue";
    month.DataBind();
    month.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "0"));
}
```

And this is the stored procedure `getMonth`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getMonth] 
    @year int,
    @upload Bit
AS
BEGIN
  IF @upload = 1
  BEGIN
   SELECT distinct datename(mm, Upload_date) month
    ,month (upload_date) monthValue
   FROM dbo.RESOLVED
   WHERE datepart(yyyy, upload_date) = @year
   ORDER by 2
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    SELECT distinct datename(mm, substring(CREATE_DT,1,2) + '.' +      substring(CREATE_DT,3,2) + '.' + substring(CREATE_DT,5,4)) month
    ,month (substring(CREATE_DT,1,2) + '.' + substring(CREATE_DT,3,2) + '.' + substring(CREATE_DT,5,4)) monthValue

    FROM dbo.RESOLVED
    WHERE datepart(yyyy, substring(CREATE_DT,1,2) + '.' + substring(CREATE_DT,3,2) + '.' + substring(CREATE_DT,5,4)) = @year
    ORDER by 2
 END
```

The stored procedure is supposed to populate dropdownlist. It supposed to execute the IF statement, but IF is skipped and ELSE is executed instead.

Comment: Have you tried passing in "1" for `upload` to see if it works?

Comment: I just updated the code, upload variable in the c# code is global and has an initial value false. Then it is assigned to true in showDate(), but somehow and stayed false in getMonthList(). The code works only if I assign true to upload variable in getMonthList(). I don't know why.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code. You might need to put several breakpoints in the code to figure it out. Is `getMonthList()` called on the same instance of the class?

Comment: Try changing `IF @upload = 1` to `IF @upload <> 0`. You're presuming that `true` is `1`, and that's often a bad presumption.

Comment: @KenWhite, `bit` values can only be 0 or 1.  It's a valid assumption to make.

Comment: @Amy: That might be true on the SQL Server side, but it's not always safe on the calling code's side. (VBA and VB, for instance, use `-1` for `true` values, which is going to fail the `= 1` test. `<> 0` should work either way. (The poster's code just assigns the `AddWithValue` without indicating the underlying column is a `bit`.)

Comment: @KenWhite, ah, understood.

Comment: @KenWhite, thank you for the good advice. I'm not sure what you mean by the underlying column, 'upload' is only a flag to check.

Comment: @gg17: Sorry. Should have been "underlying variable". IOW, I said the same thing as MrMoose; you didn't specify that the `Parameter` was `Boolean` (you just assigned using `AddWithValue`).

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to specify the type for the boolean parameter also. Maybe something like;

```
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@upload";
            param.Value = upload;
            param.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Boolean
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Maybe also check using a breakpoint or even `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("@Upload is " + upload)` to ensure you are passing in what you think you are passing in.

Lastly, I'd suggest putting your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` statments in a `using` block to ensure the resources are cleaned up after this has run.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new and didn't know about System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write, it helped me. I have another method getYearList(), that's being called before getMonthList(), there 'upload' stays true. After getYearList() is called 'upload' becomes false again. So I changed the code to declare 'upload' as static and it's good now.