# SQL procedure returns rows trhough standard query but not an application query

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Now that's a weird one, i have this procedure:

```
@ProjectId INT,
@ChecksheetId INT,
@QualId INT,
@includeDeleted BIT = 0

AS

BEGIN

SELECT  CheckSheetQual.CheckSheetQualId, CheckSheetQual.CheckSheetQualSheetId, CheckSheetQual.CheckSheetQualQualId, CheckSheetQual.CheckSheetQualProjectId, CheckSheetQual.CheckSheetQualAddedById, CheckSheetQual.CheckSheetQualAddedAt,
        CheckSheetQual.CheckSheetQualDeleted, CheckSheetQual.CheckSheetQualDeletedById, CheckSheetQual.CheckSheetQualDeletedAt,
        Quals.QualsTitle, Quals.QualsDesc, Quals.QualsDuration, DeletedUser.UserFullName AS CheckSheetQualDeletedBy,
        CheckSheetQual.CheckSheetQualAddedBy, Project.ProjectDesc, Checksheet.CheckSheetName, CheckSheetDescription, CheckSheetRevision, 
        Discipline.DisciplineRef, L_CheckTypeDesc
FROM    dbo.[ChecksheetQual] INNER JOIN
        dbo.Quals ON ChecksheetQual.CheckSheetQualQualId = Quals.QualsID INNER JOIN
        dbo.Checksheet ON Checksheet.ChecksheetId = ChecksheetQual.ChecksheetQualSheetId INNER JOIN
        dbo.Discipline ON Checksheet.ChecksheetDiscipline = Discipline.DisciplineId INNER JOIN
        dbo.L_CheckType ON Checksheet.CheckSheetType = L_CheckType.L_CheckTypeId INNER JOIN
        dbo.Project ON ChecksheetQual.ChecksheetQualProjectId = Project.ProjectId LEFT JOIN
        dbo.[User] AS DeletedUser ON ChecksheetQual.CheckSheetQualDeletedById = DeletedUser.UserId
WHERE   
        dbo.Project.ProjectId = @ProjectId
AND
        (dbo.CheckSheetQual.CheckSheetQualSheetId = @ChecksheetId)
AND

        (dbo.CheckSheetQual.CheckSheetQualDeleted = @includeDeleted)
```

select statement is a huge one, i know, but it can be ignored because i know it works, and i'll tell you why...

now lets say i want to get the items that do have includeDeleted set as 1 (deleted items) so, in sql manager i run this query:

```
EXEC dbo.prc_ChecksheetQual_Get_List @ProjectId = 1, @ChecksheetId = 378, @QualId = 0,  @includeDeleted = 1;
GO
```

results are as expected the right rows are returned, 3 of them in fact.

now lets say i want to do the SAME thing in an application:

```
 Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection(Me.Variables.ConnectionString)
        Dim sqlComm As New SqlCommand
        Dim sqlDR As SqlDataReader = Nothing

        Try
            With sqlComm
                .CommandText = "prc_ChecksheetQual_Get_List"
                .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                .CommandTimeout = Me.Variables.CommandTimeout
                .Connection = sqlConn
                .Parameters.Clear()
                .Parameters.Add("@ProjectId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1
                .Parameters.Add("@ChecksheetId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 378
                .Parameters.Add("@QualId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0
                .Parameters.Add("@includeDeleted", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 1
            End With

            If sqlConn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then sqlConn.Close()
            sqlConn.Open()
            sqlDR = sqlComm.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

            If sqlDR.HasRows Then
                list = New List(Of ChecksheetQualCLS)
                While sqlDR.Read
                    list.Add(FillDataRecord(sqlDR))
                End While
            End If
```

The SAME exact values are passed, yet it returns 0 rows, so okay, something's wrong, BUT, lets try the same but get the items that are not deleted...

```
.Parameters.Add("@includeDeleted", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 0
```

Returns the correct amount and correct rows. How is this possible???

I'm at a complete loss here, please help.

Comment: Check if you are running this query against the same database. Sometimes connectionstrings are tricky

Comment: Yeah that's definitely all right, because as my last point stated if i just set the includeDeleted to 0 everything works as expected in the app

Comment: I had something similar with a bit value parameter.  Try `Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@includeDeleted", SqlDbType.Bit))` and `cmd.Parameters["@includeDeleted"].Value = 1` on a separate line.  Not saying you should keep it that way just test to see if this is the same problem I had.

Comment: I don't want to insist, but setting includeDeleted to 0 doesn't exclude the fact that you connect to a different database with the exact number of rows with the deleted flag. What is your connection string?

Comment: Checked the string, selects the correct DB =(

Comment: @Fred cmd.Parameters["@includeDeleted"].Value = 1 Tis lines says property access must assign to the property or use it's value

Comment: @user2209644 .Parameters.Add("@includeDeleted", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = True ?

Comment: Tried True, doesn't make a difference

Comment: @user2209644 Sorry, mixing C# and Vb.Net it should read `.Parameters("@includeDeleted").Value = 1`  I had the same problem.  A bit field value 0 worked but 1 didn't.  It was down to the way I added the parameters.

Comment: @Fred The result is the same =(

Comment: @user2209644 check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536093/passing-a-boolean-parameter-to-a-sql-server-stored-procedure  Maybe try `param.DbType = DbType.Boolean`

Comment: Thank you. But Still no luck

Comment: Good grief. You should read about using aliases in queries. You would type about a zillion less characters and it would be far more legible. Also I would avoid using the table name in each column, I realize this may be outside your control but it is really silly.

Comment: I more than agree with you friend, however all of the procedures were not written by me. I do feel like strangling the developer that did though =)  unfortunately all of that chaos was done way before i joined the team

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Mysql or sql server? You have both tagged and debugging this is going to be vastly different.

Comment: My bad, edited, it's sql-server

Comment: Try using -1 instead of 1 when querying a bit.